# What if Chinese strings shown in the pandas DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, encoding, pandas

Suppose I have the data below. Even I used #coding=utf-8 to define the default encoding, the output is still showing me : ??? instead of the Chinese string.

```
#coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ '日期' : ['2015-01-07', '2014-12-17', '2015-01-21', '2014-11-19', '2015-01-17', '2015-02-26', '2015-01-04', '2014-12-20', '2014-12-07', '2015-01-06'],
                    '股票代码': ['600795', '600268', '002428', '600031', '002736', '600216', '000799', '601600', '601939', '000898']
                    })

print df
```

Comment: Is your file encoded in UTF-8? Are you running Python 3 (in Python 2, you denote unicode strings by `u"abc"`)? Is your output device (maybe a terminal?) capable of printing these characters?

Comment: I use python 2.7.5 in sublime text. And I run it in both sublime and IDLE. Neither of them showed me the Chinese words.

Comment: I get the Chinese string in Python 2.7.6 on OS X, in the commandline. What context are you running in?

Comment: I run it in IDLE, it gives me Unsupported characters in input.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: In a interactive IDLE session, what does `import sys`, `sys.stdout.encoding` equal? This is the encoding Python detects for your IDLE terminal.

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working.

Comment: What does `sys.stdout.encoding` equal?

Comment: I tried sys, not stdout, can you put the code as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
pd.options.display.encoding = sys.stdout.encoding
```

near the top of your file. By default, pandas encodes unicode with `utf-8` when encoding strings.

Python sets `sys.stdout.encoding` to the encoding it detects your console or terminal is using.

---

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.encoding = sys.stdout.encoding

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'日期' : ['2015-01-07', '2014-12-17', '2015-01-21', '2014-11-19', 
               '2015-01-17', '2015-02-26', '2015-01-04', '2014-12-20', 
               '2014-12-07', '2015-01-06'],
     '股票代码': ['600795', '600268', '002428', '600031', '002736', '600216', 
                  '000799', '601600', '601939', '000898']})

print(df)
```

---

Note that even though you defined the columns with strings, Pandas converts them to unicode:

```
In [158]: df.columns
Out[158]: Index([u'日期', u'股票代码'], dtype='object')
```

This is why when you `print(df)` Pandas is using `pd.options.display.encoding` to *encode* these values.

Comment: still does not work in IDLE, and shows SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe6' in file /Users/johnhenry/Desktop/sys.py on line 7, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: Your file `/Users/johnhenry/Desktop/sys.py` is over-shadowing the builtin module `sys`. That's a no-no. Rename your file so that `import sys` will import the `sys` module from the standard library.

Comment: okay, I changed it, but it can't show me the chinese string in IDLE.